# Latin academic positions

Tags: academic-history

I was wondering if there was a standard system, at some point in history, for academic positions in Latin.

What I mean is that today each country has a standard system that names each academic position, for example in England if you are the head of a university you will be called a "chancellor", regardless which university you head, as long as it is in England.

Different countries today use different words for different positions, some are derived from Latin, some are not. I was wondering if there ever was a standard of Latin-language academic position titles that have been used in the past at some point by several or more countries? Because I'd wager some countries had Latin titles but they were the only ones to use them.

Comment: History of Science and Mathematics may be better suited to answer: [link](http://hsm.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @J.Doe, I will try, but honestly I think it isn't the appropriate place, at all.

Comment: Now that I look closer you may be right; although it certainly wouldn't be the first question about naming-conventions there either... Their exact scope remains a bit vague to me.

Comment: Or you can ask on [history.se].

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, they told me to ask here. :)

Comment: Seems like a reasonable fit here. Hopefully you will get an answer.

Comment: You should limit the scope of your question. As it is, one could answer with academic positions in the Roman empire.

Comment: @Roland, oh, sorry, it seems I have omitted to add a bit of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no homogeneous system to name the position in LA. Moreover, there is no unique academic structure. This situation is a source of misunderstanding and many times you cannot find the equivalence position.
An example in Uruguay: In Medicine, as undegraduate you can be student or (last year) internship. In a Department of a Faculty (named "Clinica") you can be (in order) Resident, Chief of Clinic (also named grade II), Assistant Professor (also named grade III), Agregate Professor (also named grade IV) and lastly Titular Professor (also named grade V). Hope to help in some way.